# Get URL when calling by WebClient DownloadString in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I get the calling url in MVC razor when it is calling by WebClient DownloadString. let me explain by example what I want to say :).

Suppose there are 2 projects. Proj-A and Proj-B.

In Proj-A below is the code written for calling Proj-B page.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    string html = client.DownloadString("Proj-B/View1");
}
```

Now in View1 how can I get the calling url of Proj-A.

Comment: Add a custom request header (or re-purpose the Referrer header) or include the A url in the request url sent to B (/View1?callerurl=XXX)

Comment: well I am thinking why HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is not given me the url of Proj-A :( , I need something like this.

Comment: You need to set it, it wont be there by default; `client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://proj.a.com/bla");`

Comment: Any thing else ? I tried header also.

Comment: Did you try @AlexK. suggestion? I think you can't get it out of the box, since your client might be a desktop or mobile application, so there wouldn't exist a url at all. You could try to get the client's ip/domain, or you can explicit pass it like the suggestions above. By the way, would you mind telling us why do you need this? Maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Okies yes it is working actually the other Proj-B was emptying the Referer in OnActionExecuting :) Alex K can you write the proper answer so I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: You can answer & accept yourself, I didn't know about OnActionExecuting + Referer so if you mention that it will be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it, it wont be there by default; client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://proj.a.com/bla");

Please read the comments also.